# regex.h performance

Tags: python, c, regex, cython

I'm trying to figure out counter-intuitive performance differences between Python, Cython and pure C with regex matching.

There is a small sample program that takes a source text file (17 KB), a dictionary of 2000 words, creates a regex with those words (word1|word2|...), and finds all instances of said dictionary in the source file.

First, I've done a pure Python implementation which looks like this:

```
def scanFile(filename, patterns):
   pattern_regex = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))
   pageContent = open(filename).read()
   matchingPatterns = set()
   for matchObj in pattern_regex.finditer(pageContent):
      matchingPatterns.add(matchObj.group(0))

   return matchingPatterns
```

Then, I've tried optimising this by reimplementing the same with Cython, on top of `regex.h` rather than Python's `re` module.

```
cdef extern from "regex.h" nogil:
   ctypedef struct regmatch_t:
      int rm_so
      int rm_eo
   ctypedef struct regex_t:
      pass
   int REG_EXTENDED
   int regcomp(regex_t* preg, const char* regex, int cflags)
   int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch, regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags)
   void regfree(regex_t* preg) 

def matchPatterns(bytes pageContent, bytes regex):
   cdef set matchingPatterns = set()
   cdef regex_t regex_obj
   cdef regmatch_t regmatch_obj[1]
   cdef int regex_res = 0
   cdef int current_str_pos = 0

   regcomp(&regex_obj, regex, REG_EXTENDED)
   regex_res = regexec(&regex_obj, pageContent[current_str_pos:], 1, regmatch_obj, 0)
   while regex_res == 0:
      matchingPatterns.add(pageContent[current_str_pos + regmatch_obj[0].rm_so: current_str_pos + regmatch_obj[0].rm_eo])
      current_str_pos += regmatch_obj[0].rm_eo
      regex_res = regexec(&regex_obj, pageContent[current_str_pos:], 1, regmatch_obj, 0)

   regfree(&regex_obj)
   return matchingPatterns
```

Performance, however, turned out to be precisely the other way around: Cython+regex.h takes about 2.34 sec and Python takes 0.92 sec.

After running a bit of profiling and custom commented out code, I confirmed the suspicion that it's down to `regexec` which takes 10s of milliseconds on each invocation.

Just to make sure it's not Cython that's at fault, prepared a standalone C unit test which uses the same inputs and regex.h, and it also showed worse results than Python (about 1.60 sec, i.e. 60% slower than Python).

So, with all of that, I'd be thankful for any insight into why `regexec` has such a poor performance.

I'm running this on Python 2.7.10, gcc 4.9.2, Cython 0.22, and the platform is Cygwin/Windows. I had a similar discrepancy when running the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have the code for the standalone C unit test?

Comment: Why would you assume that C's regular expression engine is faster than the ones used in the various Python implementations? They're all probably running as native C code, and there are many variations possible when implementing a regular expression engine.

Comment: You probably need a wider range of REs before you can jump to conclusions about performance.  You might have found a weakness in one RE engine but missed its strengths simply because you are only trying an OR.  Other code might be implicated, e.g. you are using a `set()` in Python, did you do the same in C?

Comment: One possible implementation of BRE/ERE is to implement it on top of a backtracking engine - and instead of the accept node at the end, it keeps track of the longest match and let the engine continue to try until it exhausts all the possibility. As a result, such implementation ends up doing more work than a backtracking engine. As for the reason of doing this - since BRE supports backreference, it's necessary to implement a backtracking engine anyway. It's possible that they don't bother to include an efficient implementation for patterns without backreference.

Comment: @unwind - Mostly because python `re` performance was far worse than boost::regex. Since I wanted to trial Cython (both learning experience and optimisation), I went for regex.h since it's pure C. I realise that it's possible to include C++ in Cython and that boost::regex and regex.h are not born equal, but my hope was to get similar gains in both. The discrepancy prompted the question.

@cdarke - Indeed, it may well be that a large pattern of ORs is something that Python copes with better. It's not clear though from regex.h documentation that it does _not_ cope well with it.

Comment: @nhahtdh - You probably have the root cause in your answer. C code is very similar to Cython, but I can add it if need be.
As other comments mentioned, it seems like Python's regex engine is simply better at this sort of pattern(and `boost::regex` is even faster than that).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what is in the question I can assume several problems:
-You are using POSIX on Windows, and Cygwin - this is overhead, Windows is not POSIX system.
-There is comparison between pcre (let me assume pcre2) and regex.h
-Standalone compiled code differs from exported functions (compiler cannot assume anything)
-Standalone C program has big footprint tells you that recompilation of pattern or some other stuff is happening under the hood.
-compilation options, and potential aliasing are always hard to compare.

Apart from source for standalone program, always using translators/transpilers may give lags.
Optimisation is nowadays task to give your compiler clean idea what you are doing and let it work.

And sorry for this part, not related to question per se, but it looks like you do not need RE but basic string matching algorithm or some neat structure like prefix tree and simple loop to do your task.